# Transforming object of objects in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I am fairly new to JS and React and I am stuck with the following problem (maybe it is simple but I don't know how to solve this).

This is the object that I have:

```
{
  React: {
    title: 'React',
    questions: [
      {
        question: 'What is React?',
        answer: 'A library for managing user interfaces'
      },
      {
        question: 'Where do you make Ajax requests in React?',
        answer: 'The componentDidMount lifecycle event'
      }
    ]
  },
  JavaScript: {
    title: 'JavaScript',
    questions: [
      {
        question: 'What is a closure?',
        answer: 'The combination of a function and the lexical environment within which that function was declared.'
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

And this is what I need:

```
[
  { title: "React", questions: 2},
  { title: "JavaScript", questions: 1}
]
```

I already tried `Object.keys` and then mapping over it - which gives me either the titles or questions in a new array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Object.keys is the way to go.

```js
const data = {
  React: {
    title: 'React',
    questions: [
      {
        question: 'What is React?',
        answer: 'A library for managing user interfaces'
      },
      {
        question: 'Where do you make Ajax requests in React?',
        answer: 'The componentDidMount lifecycle event'
      }
    ]
  },
  JavaScript: {
    title: 'JavaScript',
    questions: [
      {
        question: 'What is a closure?',
        answer: 'The combination of a function and the lexical environment within which that function was declared.'
      }
    ]
  }
};

const newArray = Object.keys(data).map((key) => {
  return {
    title: data[key].title,
    questions: data[key].questions.length
  }
});

console.log(newArray)
```

Answer (score 3):

You could map over `Object.values` and extract values you need.

```js
const data = {
  React: {
    title: 'React',
    questions: [{
        question: 'What is React?',
        answer: 'A library for managing user interfaces'
      },
      {
        question: 'Where do you make Ajax requests in React?',
        answer: 'The componentDidMount lifecycle event'
      }
    ]
  },
  JavaScript: {
    title: 'JavaScript',
    questions: [{
      question: 'What is a closure?',
      answer: 'The combination of a function and the lexical environment within which that function was declared.'
    }]
  }
}

console.log(
  Object.values(data).map(({
    title,
    questions: {
      length: questions
    }
  }) => ({
    title,
    questions
  }))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

it is more clear and simple using lodash's **reduce**, because it can iterate object like an array:

```
import { reduce } from 'lodash';

const newData = reduce(
  data,
  (acc, { title, questions }) => [
    ...acc,
    { title, questions: questions.length },
  ],
  []
);
```